# Continuous audio throughout page transitions

Tags: audio, navigation, sveltekit

So I understand that auto-play of audio is blocked by browsers until the user has interacted with the page. But, let's say I give my user an opening prompt asking if they want to enable audio for the website, and if they click yes, I want to play audio in the background continuously, even when they navigate to different pages. From what I know, anytime you load a page, any audio that was playing stops. This is all pretty easy to do with an SPA like Svelte or React (I just "fake" page transitions and load different components), but I would love to do this and have the address bar and the back button actually be useful.

I'm using Sveltekit, which allows you to render components across multiple pages, but I still get my audio element getting turned off by the browser when I navigate to new pages.

Comment: How do you navigate? There should not be a page reload on client-side navigation unless a version change is detected.

Comment: I'm using Sveltekit, which I'm new to, and I'm just using regular links <a href="some-page"></a>

Answer (score 0):

How are you playing the audio? The audio may stop playing because the associated component was unloaded/destroyed on navigation.

Try putting the audio code in [+layout.svelte](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-svelte) so the component associated with the audio is not unloaded.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing.